# Inversion in a sentence with the continuous tense

Tags: inversion

The original sentence is

> The two men were talking in front of the station.

Which one of the following sentences is correct, if I place the adverbial phrase at the beginning?

> In front of the station, the two men **were** talking.
>
> In front of the station **were** the two men talking.

Comment: You are missing commas in the sentences. Also i think the first one is more appropriate

Comment: @TalhaIsrar A comma would not be appropriate in the second sentence.

Comment: yes only in the first

Comment: my mistake i typed plural sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use either of those.

"In front of the station, the two men were talking" - this is quite a neutral statement and just says that they were talking.

"In front of the station, were the two men talking" - this could have a more specific meaning, e.g. if I had been looking for the men for a while but couldn't find them. And look -- in front of the station, were the two men talking! (Or if you want to draw attention to the specific fact that the men were there, in some way... like if outside the station it is normally empty)

In a general example of "inversion in sentences" I would go with your first example.

Comment: ”In front of the station, were the two men talking” does not require a comma.